# Text column not storing more than 8000 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, flat-file

I researched this and found that a `text` column in SQL Server can store a lot more than 8000 characters. But when I run the following insert in the text column, it only inserts 8000 characters:

```
UPDATE  a
SET [File] = b.Header + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + d.Detail + c.Trailer + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(26)
FROM Summary a
JOIN #Header b ON b.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
JOIN #Trailer c ON c.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
JOIN #Detail d ON d.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
WHERE   
    a.SummaryId = @SummaryId
```

I am trying to generate a fixed width flat file and every row should be 3900 characters long, and they are in the respective temp tables. But when I do the insert in the permanent table, the Trailer data gets truncated.

I am adding char(10) + char(13) to add carriage return and line feed and char(26) for end of file, and it seems like they are adding characters to the fixed width layout.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s Your answer is correct too, my initial testing didn't hit the 8000 character limit, added explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is not the data type of the field that you store the value in, it's the type of the value that you put together to store in it.

The type of `b.Header` is not `text` but `varchar`, which is used as type for the whole expression. When the strings are concatenated, the result will be truncated to fit in a `varchar` value.

If you cast the first string to `text`, the whole expression gets that type, and can become longer than 8000 characters:

```
SET [File] = cast(b.Header as text) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + d.Detail + c.Trailer + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(26)
```

Naturally you should transition into using the new type `varchar(max)` instead of `text`, but that is not the reason for your problem.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it (and the answer by Goat CO).

Answer (score 3):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx `TEXT` fields are deprecated.  Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` fields instead.  They should support 2GB in text.

Answer (score 1):

Your source fields aren't `VARCHAR(MAX)`, so there is an 8000 character limit when concatenating them together, you can fix this by casting the first source field in the concat list as `VARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
UPDATE  a
SET [File] = CAST(b.Header AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + d.Detail + c.Trailer + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(26)
FROM Summary a
JOIN #Header b ON b.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
JOIN #Trailer c ON c.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
JOIN #Detail d ON d.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
WHERE a.SummaryId = @SummaryId
```

If you concat a thousand `VARCHAR(25)` fields together, the length of the resulting string would be 8000, as that's the limit of the `VARCHAR()` type when supplied a numeric length.  `VARCHAR(MAX)` does not share this limit, but the concat list inherets the type of the first string supplied.  It's an interesting behavior, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT` is deprecated - don't use it! Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead!

I think you need to explicitly cast all columns that you use in your `UPDATE` statement to `VARCHAR(MAX)` in order for this to work:

```
UPDATE  a
SET [File] = CAST(b.Header AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 
             CAST(d.Detail AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(c.Trailer AS VARCHAR(MAX))) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(26)
FROM Summary a
JOIN #Header b ON b.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
JOIN #Trailer c ON c.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
JOIN #Detail d ON d.SummaryId = a.SummaryId
WHERE   
    a.SummaryId = @SummaryId
```