# why varchar(max) is not storing data more than 8000 charaters

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to store a string more than 8000 characters so I used VARCHAR(MAX) because its limit is 2gb.

please correct me if I am wrong Varchar(max) stores data in IN_ROW_DATA pages if the string is less than or equal to 8000. If the string is greater than 8000 then it starts storing the string in in LOB_DATA pages and pointer is stored in IN_ROW_DATA pages.

My code below is not storing the string greater than 8000 characters.

```
create table test(name varchar(max))
insert into test
values(replicate('a',8001)

Select len(name) from test
```

-- This will still give me length of 8000 and not 8001. So in this case there is no difference between varchar(max) and varchar(8000).

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how to store string greater than 8000 characters.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/varcharmax-field-cutting-off-data-after-8000-characters-sql-server-2008

Comment: I hope this link help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041718/text-column-not-storing-more-than-8000-characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041718/text-column-not-storing-more-than-8000-characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are truncating the data to 8000 bytes before inserting it. To create a value longer than 8000 characters you must use varchar(max) data type, whereas the type of 'a' is just varchar.

```
create table test(name varchar(max))
insert into test
values(replicate(CAST('a' AS varchar(MAX)), 100000));

select len(name) from test;
```

Comment: There are some paranthesis missing (corrected this). Your answer is the best one, delete mine and vote yours up.