# Cannot create a row of size xxx which is greater than the maximum row size of 8060

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have seen this question asked quite a few times and most of them end with a logical explanation.  My table doesn't seem to be anywhere near the maximum row size.

My Dev Server is SQL 2008 Express Edition

This is my table definition.  I have one varchar(max) column and the rest of my columns should be tiny.  The "Notes" filed didn't contain much text, only a few characters.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PegBoard](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OwnersCorporationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PegNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DepositRequired] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [KeyRegister] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Locked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [NonLoanable] [bit] NULL,
    [DepositAmount] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [LastReviewedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PegBoard] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [PegBoard_PN_Cnst] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [PegNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I insert a row I receive the following message.

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot create a row of size
>   8066 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

The statement has been terminated.
I have seen a similar warning when I added new columns to the table but it didn't seem to cause a failure until now.

Any ideas what could cause this problem and what I might try to fix it.

Thanks in Advance
David

## Update

Here is the structure of my Audit Table if that helps.
The trigger itself is quite complicated as it was generated from some code I found that does all tables automatically.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](
[AuditID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Type] [char](1) NULL,
[TableName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[PrimaryKeyField] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[PrimaryKeyValue] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[FieldName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[OldValue] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[NewValue] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
[UserName] [varchar](128) NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Is there any trigger on this table? Btw: Why is your PK a non-clustered index? As it is `IDENTITY` is would perfectly fit to be a clustered PK...

Comment: I'm not that much of an expert to know the difference between Clustered and non clustered indexes.  This application has been working OK for years with a SQL database and an Access 97 Front end.  My boss finally got sick of the Access front end and I have been asked to redo it in visual studio.  I did the original database design but it was years ago.  The only think I can think of is that Access has somehow padded the notes field with spaces making it needlessly large.  I can't prove this though.

Comment: Your table as you've shown in the question can't exceed 8060 bytes per row. You can try to run `INSERT` statement in SSMS and you should work fine. The error message is an exception from .NET client. There must be something wrong with .NET code.

Comment: I have created an audit trigger on each table that writes modifications out to a single audit table if this makes any difference.

Comment: Or, this exception and error is caused by a different table, not the one that you've shown in the question. Check your code.

Comment: Just in short: a clustered index affects the physical storage of your data. The rows will be sorted on the harddisc. This allows the clustered index "know" all row's columns. Thus it is the perfect lookup key for all other indexes... But it is important to have an implicitly sorted key (perfect with IDENTITY, bad with UNIQUEIDENTIFIER).

Comment: "Audit triggers..." That was my first idea... What is the structure of your audit table?

Comment: Check your audit table and trigger. It is quite likely that the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common misunderstanding, that using VARCHAR(MAX) is a good idea in any cases... If you really have to deal with strings larger than 8000 bytes you could think about `VARBINARY(MAX)` or `XML`.

Read this: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar(n)-anymore/

But it **may** work: Read this: [why row insert above 8053 bytes not giving error when it should because max allowed row limit is 8060](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33032114/5089204)

Another problem with VARCHAR(MAX) is, that in some statements the implicitly used data type is the "normal" varchar and you need extra casts:
Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031838/5089204

Conclusio: If you do not expect really large text it's better to use a `VARCHAR(XX)`definition.

Comment: I'll try exporting my table then recreating that field using Varchar(1000).  Although it would seem at least on the face of it that Varchar(Max) is supposed to avoid the exact problem that it is causing.

Comment: Your update shows, that your audit table cannot deal with content larger than VARCHAR(1000). That's problem the point where your text would be truncated... And yes (and no): VARCHAR(MAX) was designed for bigger text. But there are many, many functions (system and indiv) delivering VARCHAR(XXX). Their parameters and return types arent v(max).. If my answer was helpful, please vote it up and mark it as the accepted answer, thx!

Comment: That makes sense now.  The audit table was overrunning the size.  I created a script that Unloads the data into a new table with the new data type varchar(1000)  I just truncated the field as anything that big was probably unimportant anyway.  I then dropped the old table and renamed the new table back to the original name.  I had to muck around a bit with dropping and recreating constraints.  I have saved the script so I can repeat the process when I update my program in production.  Thanks for your assistance. :)

Comment: It was easier to truncate large text within you trigger using `LEFT(YourColumn, 1000)`. Another easy approach would be to change your audit table to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. And, last but not least: If you first truncate you table's data with `UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn=LEFT...` it should make it possible to change your column to `VARCHAR(1000)`simply using `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR(1000)` This way you don't have to muck around with constraints...